# Using old Direct X SDK in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, macros, directx

I have some troubles after porting my project to Visual Studio 2013 more precisely with Direct X SDK.
It results with a lot of macro redefinition warnings like:

> warning C4005: 'D2DERR_BAD_NUMBER' : macro redefinition
>   warning
>   C4005: 'D2DERR_DISPLAY_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED' : macro redefinition

I know that it's caused because Windows Kit 8.1 already have Direct X SDK "installed" but I would like to use my old one (Which is already include to my project) and don't use the one from Windows Kit anymore.
Thank's.

Comment: make sure your include directories don't point to the newer sdk, or at least make sure the newer sdk is later in the include path.

Comment: @Wimmel The problem is that I never include the newer sdk in my project.

Comment: There are two sets of include directories, project specific and machine specific. They will be used both in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need your OLD dxSDK installed and then set correct paths to it in your VS 2013 project. By default VS2013 will use DirectX 11 directories/headers of course.

But if you just need to support hardware that is not Dx11 compatible you can still use DirectX 11(latest) SDK, shipped with VS2013, but target old hardware (Directx9) with feature levels.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Paths seems to be correct, also, I have to use the old SDK. Thank's for you answer!